# Playing around with Transformer - accuracy not improving

Tags: deep-learning, transformer, pytorch, large-language-models

I am playing around with a decoder only transformer model,

The Colab is here if you find that easier
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1SHyJ9Oa3E4j1x8YFlXQbd1mjUjWhHGOV#scrollTo=60e13119
or see the code below (should run with minimal deps in a notebook)

#### Goal:

1. I am playing around to understand the transformer architecture. I wanted to build a minimal version of a decoder only model and see if i can train the model to predict the last digit in this sequence (think of it as a recall function from a key value store).
2. Want to get an intuitive understanding on the linear transformations of the weight matrices to the sequence input + positional encodings.

```
n9 v8 a5 p7 k0 j1 i3 e2 g6 c4 c - (should be 4)
d5 t3 q8 r7 y1 i0 c2 n9 s4 u6 i - (should be 0) ...
l8 u9 p5 y3 f7 k0 g6 v4 r1 x2 l
a7 x5 b6 v0 i1 f3 z9 d4 y2 k8 x
m9 h4 g5 t2 l3 f1 w7 b6 a8 j0 g
x0 g7 q9 u2 j8 v4 h3 o1 f5 r6 r
r6 c4 d0 p3 j2 g9 a7 n1 e8 l5 d
r2 z7 y6 x5 v4 u1 s3 a8 l9 p0 z
k0 u3 t1 r4 g8 p2 j5 x9 s7 v6 t
o7 a1 u3 r2 k6 j0 m8 y9 e4 c5 j
```

#### Questions:

- The accuracy is not improving, so i guess there is some fundamental issue with the model. It looks like it is learning that it is a digit, but not what digit.

#### Code:

````
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
import torch.optim as optim
import random
import string
import time
import math

if torch.cuda.is_available(): 
    dev = "cuda:0" 
else: 
    dev = "cpu" 
device = torch.device(dev) 

class PositionalEncoding(nn.Module):
    """
    compute sinusoid encoding.
    """
    def __init__(self, d_model, max_len, device):
        """
        constructor of sinusoid encoding class

        :param d_model: dimension of model
        :param max_len: max sequence length
        :param device: hardware device setting
        """
        super(PositionalEncoding, self).__init__()

        # same size with input matrix (for adding with input matrix)
        self.encoding = torch.zeros(max_len, d_model, device=device)
        self.encoding.requires_grad = False  # we don't need to compute gradient

        pos = torch.arange(0, max_len, device=device)
        pos = pos.float().unsqueeze(dim=1)
        # 1D => 2D unsqueeze to represent word's position

        _2i = torch.arange(0, d_model, step=2, device=device).float()
        # 'i' means index of d_model (e.g. embedding size = 50, 'i' = [0,50])
        # "step=2" means 'i' multiplied with two (same with 2 * i)

        self.encoding[:, 0::2] = torch.sin(pos / (10000 ** (_2i / d_model)))
        self.encoding[:, 1::2] = torch.cos(pos / (10000 ** (_2i / d_model)))
        # compute positional encoding to consider positional information of words

    def forward(self, x):
        # self.encoding
        # [max_len = 512, d_model = 512]

        batch_size, seq_len, d_model = x.size()
        #print("seq_len: ", seq_len, " batch_size: ", batch_size, "d_model: ", d_model)
        # [batch_size = 128, seq_len = 31]
        #print("self.encoding: ", self.encoding[:seq_len, :].shape)
        return self.encoding[:seq_len, :d_model]
        # [seq_len = 30, d_model = 512]
        # it will add with tok_emb : [128, 30, 512]   

# Generate random strings
def random_string(length):
    #return "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9"
    a = random.sample(string.ascii_lowercase, length)
    d = random.sample(string.digits, length)
    r = ' '.join([a[i] + d[i] for i in range(length)])
    n = random.randint(0, length)-1
    return r + " " + a[n] + d[n]

# Synthetic Dataset
class RandomStringDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, num_samples, seq_length):
        self.num_samples = num_samples
        self.seq_length = seq_length
        self.data = [random_string(seq_length) for _ in range(num_samples)]

    def __len__(self):
        return self.num_samples

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        input_seq = self.data[idx][:-1]
        target_seq = self.data[idx][1:]
        return input_seq, target_seq

# Tokenizer and detokenizer functions
def tokenize(text):
    return [char for char in text]

def detokenize(tokens):
    return ''.join(tokens)

# Map characters to indices and vice versa
vocab = string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits + " "
char_to_idx = {char: idx for idx, char in enumerate(vocab)}
idx_to_char = {idx: char for idx, char in enumerate(vocab)}


# Convert tokens to tensor
def tokens_to_tensor(tokens):
    indices = [char_to_idx[token] for token in tokens]
    return torch.tensor(indices, device=device)

# Convert tensor to tokens
def tensor_to_tokens(tensor):
    return [idx_to_char[idx.item()] for idx in tensor]

def collate_fn(batch):
    inputs, targets = zip(*batch)
    input_tensors = [tokens_to_tensor(seq) for seq in inputs]
    target_tensors = [tokens_to_tensor(seq) for seq in targets]
    return torch.stack(input_tensors), torch.stack(target_tensors)

class DecoderOnlyTransformer(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, vocab_size, d_model, nhead, num_layers):
        super(DecoderOnlyTransformer, self).__init__()
        self.pe = PositionalEncoding(d_model, 128, device)
        self.embedding = nn.Embedding(vocab_size, d_model)
        self.transformer_decoder = nn.TransformerDecoder(
            nn.TransformerDecoderLayer(d_model, nhead),
            num_layers
        )
        self.fc = nn.Linear(d_model, vocab_size)
        
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.embedding(x)
        pe = self.pe(x)
        #print("x: ", x.shape)
        #print("pe: ", pe.shape)
        x = x + pe
        tgt = torch.zeros_like(x)
        output = self.transformer_decoder(x, x)
        output = self.fc(output)
        return output
    
# Hyperparameters

seq_length = 10
batch_size = 16
num_samples = batch_size*1000
learning_rate = 0.001
num_epochs = 100
d_model = 4
nhead = 4
num_layers = 2
vocab_size = len(vocab)

# Create dataset
dataset = RandomStringDataset(num_samples, seq_length)
train_loader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True, collate_fn=collate_fn)

# Initialize model, loss, and optimizer
model = DecoderOnlyTransformer(vocab_size, d_model, nhead, num_layers)
model.to(device)


criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
lr = 5  # learning rate
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=lr)
scheduler = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.StepLR(optimizer, 1.0, gamma=0.95)

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    correct = 0
    count = 0
    total_loss = 0
    start_time = 0
    log_interval = 100
    num_batches = int(num_samples/batch_size)
    for inputs, targets in train_loader:
        
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        outputs = model(inputs)
        loss = criterion(outputs.reshape(-1, len(vocab)), targets.flatten())

        probabilities = torch.softmax(outputs[0, -1], dim=-1)
        next_token_idx = torch.argmax(probabilities).item()
        token = idx_to_char[next_token_idx]

        if idx_to_char[targets[0, -1].item()] == token:
            correct+=1
        count+=1
        
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(model.parameters(), 0.5)
        optimizer.step()
        
        total_loss += loss.item()
        if count % log_interval == 0 and count > 0:
            lr = scheduler.get_last_lr()[0]
            ms_per_batch = (time.time() - start_time) * 1000 / log_interval
            cur_loss = total_loss / log_interval
            ppl = math.exp(cur_loss)
            print(f'| epoch {epoch:3d} | {count:5d}/{num_batches:5d} batches | '
                  f'lr {lr:02.2f} | ms/batch {ms_per_batch:5.2f} | '
                  f'loss {cur_loss:5.2f} | ppl {ppl:8.2f} | '
                  f'Acc: {correct/count}'
                 )
            total_loss = 0
            start_time = time.time()    
    print(f'Epoch: {epoch + 1}/{num_epochs}, Loss: {loss.item()}  Count: {count}')
```
````

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the solution to this was that I was randomizing both the key (a-z) and the value (0-9). That was too hard for a simple model to learn, so only randomizing the value worked. I also changed the positional embedding to be learned, which improved learning speed.

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
import torch.optim as optim
import random
import string
import time
import math

if torch.cuda.is_available(): 
    dev = "cuda:0" 
else: 
    dev = "cpu" 
device = torch.device(dev) 


def flatten(l):
    return [item for sublist in l for item in sublist]

def random_string(length):
    a = string.ascii_lowercase[0:length]
    d = random.sample(string.digits, length)
    r = ' '.join([a[i] + d[i] for i in range(length)])
    n = random.randint(0, length)-1
    return r + " " + a[n] + d[n]

# Synthetic Dataset
class RandomStringDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, num_samples, seq_length):
        self.num_samples = num_samples
        self.seq_length = seq_length
        self.data = [random_string(seq_length) for _ in range(num_samples)]

    def __len__(self):
        return self.num_samples

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        input_seq = self.data[idx][:-1]
        target_seq = self.data[idx][1:]
        return input_seq, target_seq

# Tokenizer and detokenizer functions
def tokenize(text):
    return [char for char in text]

def detokenize(tokens):
    return ''.join(tokens)

# Map characters to indices and vice versa
vocab = string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits + " "
char_to_idx = {char: idx for idx, char in enumerate(vocab)}
idx_to_char = {idx: char for idx, char in enumerate(vocab)}


# Convert tokens to tensor
def tokens_to_tensor(tokens):
    indices = [char_to_idx[token] for token in tokens]
    return torch.tensor(indices, device=device)


# Convert tensor to tokens
def tensor_to_tokens(tensor):
    return [idx_to_char[idx.item()] for idx in tensor]

def collate_fn(batch):
    inputs, targets = zip(*batch)
    input_tensors = [tokens_to_tensor(seq) for seq in inputs]
    target_tensors = [tokens_to_tensor(seq) for seq in targets]
    return torch.stack(input_tensors), torch.stack(target_tensors)

class DecoderOnlyTransformer(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, vocab_size, d_model, nhead, num_layers):
        super(DecoderOnlyTransformer, self).__init__()
        self.pe = nn.Embedding(32, d_model)
        self.embedding = nn.Embedding(vocab_size, d_model)
        self.transformer_decoder = nn.TransformerDecoder(
            nn.TransformerDecoderLayer(d_model, nhead, batch_first=True),
            num_layers
        )
        self.ln = nn.LayerNorm(d_model)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(d_model, vocab_size)
        
    def forward(self, x):
        B, T = x.shape
        x = self.embedding(x) + self.pe(torch.arange(T, device=device))
        output = self.transformer_decoder(x, x)
        output = self.ln(output)
        output = self.fc(output)
        return output
    
# Hyperparameters

seq_length = 10
batch_size = 16
num_samples = batch_size*1000
num_epochs = 10
d_model = 32
nhead = 4
num_layers = 2
vocab_size = len(vocab)

# Create dataset
dataset = RandomStringDataset(num_samples, seq_length)
train_loader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True, collate_fn=collate_fn)

# Initialize model, loss, and optimizer
model = DecoderOnlyTransformer(vocab_size, d_model, nhead, num_layers)
model.to(device)

criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
lr = 5  # learning rate
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=lr)
scheduler = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.StepLR(optimizer, 1.0, gamma=0.95)

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    correct = 0
    count = 0
    total_loss = 0
    start_time = 0
    log_interval = 100
    num_batches = int(num_samples/batch_size)
    for inputs, targets in train_loader:
        
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        outputs = model(inputs)
        loss = criterion(outputs.reshape(-1, len(vocab)), targets.flatten())

        probabilities = torch.softmax(outputs[0, -1], dim=-1)
        next_token_idx = torch.argmax(probabilities).item()
        token = idx_to_char[next_token_idx]

        if idx_to_char[targets[0, -1].item()] == token:
            correct+=1
        count+=1
        
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(model.parameters(), 0.5)
        optimizer.step()
        
        total_loss += loss.item()
        if count % log_interval == 0 and count > 0:
            lr = scheduler.get_last_lr()[0]
            ms_per_batch = (time.time() - start_time) * 1000 / log_interval
            cur_loss = total_loss / log_interval
            ppl = math.exp(cur_loss)
            print(f'| epoch {epoch:3d} | {count:5d}/{num_batches:5d} batches | '
                  f'lr {lr:02.2f} | ms/batch {ms_per_batch:5.2f} | '
                  f'loss {cur_loss:5.2f} | ppl {ppl:8.2f} | '
                  f'Acc: {correct/count}'
                 )
            total_loss = 0
            start_time = time.time()    
    print(f'Epoch: {epoch + 1}/{num_epochs}, Loss: {loss.item()}  Count: {count}')
    
    
# Some evaluation
rs = random_string(10)
print(rs)
t = torch.argmax(torch.softmax(model(tokens_to_tensor(tokenize(rs))[:-1].reshape(1, -1)), dim=-1), dim=-1)
"".join(tensor_to_tokens(t[0]))
```